# KnockoutJS custom binding calling click event during bind, not on click

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I`m attempting to bind an observable array of people two a two column responsive layout with click events using knockoutjs.

I have created a custom binding called TwoCol that loops through the array, and appends nodes to the DOM to create my suggested layout, but the click events are giving me trouble when I try to apply them in a custom binding nested in a loop.

I have played with it quite a bit, and encountered all types of results, but where I`m at now is calling my ~click~ event during binding, rather than on click.

http://jsfiddle.net/5SPVm/6/

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="TwoCol: Friends" id="" style="padding: 20px">
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function FriendsModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.Friends = ko.observableArray();
    this.SelectedFriend = "";
    this.SetSelected = function (person) {
        alert(person);
        self.SelectedFriend = person;
    }
}
function isOdd(num) {
    return num % 2;
}
ko.bindingHandlers.TwoCol = {
    update: function (elem, valueAccessor) {
        var i = 0;
        var rowDiv;
        var vFriends = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(elem).html('');
        while (i < vFriends.length) {
            //create row container every other iteration
            if (!isOdd(i)) {
                rowDiv = document.createElement("div");
                $(rowDiv).addClass("row-fluid");
                elem.appendChild(rowDiv);
            }
            //add column for every iteration
            var colDiv = document.createElement("div");
            $(colDiv).addClass("span6");
            rowDiv.appendChild(colDiv);
            //actual code has fairly complex button html here
            var htmlDiv = document.createElement("div");
            var htmlButton = vFriends[i]
            htmlDiv.innerHTML = htmlButton;
            colDiv.appendChild(htmlDiv);
            //i think i need to add the event to the template too?
            //$(htmlDiv).attr("data-bind", "click: { alert: $data }")
            //it seems that the SetSelected Method is called while looping
            ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(htmlDiv, { click: friends.SetSelected(vFriends[i]) });
            i++;
        }
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
}

var friends = new FriendsModel();
friends.Friends.push('bob');
friends.Friends.push('rob');
friends.Friends.push('mob');
friends.Friends.push('lob');
ko.applyBindings(friends);
```

Comment: The code in the fiddle doesn't match what you have here and has several syntax errors

Comment: ok, I hit update now (and appended /6/), give it a try again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're using `ko.applyBindingsToDescendants` correctly.  I admit I'm a little confused as to the meaning of some of the values in your code, so I may have interpreted something incorrectly.

Here's a fiddle where I think it's working the way you intended: 
<del>http://jsfiddle.net/5SPVm/7/</del>
http://jsfiddle.net/5SPVm/8/

Notice if manually control descendant bindings (`return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };`), you need to set that up in the init callback, instead of update.  The update callback is too late for that.

Quick rundown of the changes **(edited)**:

1. Moved the `controlsDescendantBindings` into the `init` binding callback
2. Added the necessary parameter names to the binding param list to access additional values.
3. I re-enabled the html.attr call.  Notice that now, because the binding context is set to the actual item, the SetSelected method doesn't exist at that level anymore, so it is necessary to use `$parent.SetSelected`.

   ```
           $(htmlDiv).attr("data-bind", "click: $parent.SetSelected")
   ```
4. Fixed the `ko.applyBindingsToDescendants` call.  This method takes a binding context, which is created from the current binding context, and also takes the element to apply the binding to.  You don't want to reapply the binding, which is why this whole thing needs to be in the init handler.

   ```
           var childBindingContext = bindingContext.createChildContext(vFriends[i]);
       ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(childBindingContext, colDiv);
   ```

Comment: Thank you!  That works great, but in my production scenario, all the items are added after the initial binding, and it doesn't appear to be calling the init as they are pushed.  Might you help me split the code between the init and update to fit that scenario?  I "fiddled" with your fiddle but it's just giving me headaches.

Comment: I was wrong about the applyBindingsToDescendants being in init.  I'll update the answer.  `controlDescendantsBindings:true` *does* need to be in init.  Everything else is fine in update.  http://jsfiddle.net/5SPVm/8/.